# How to update tableviewcell using back button?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have this tableviewcontroller and detailviewcontroller which has a text field, when the user clicks the tableviewcell it goes to text field and the user could able to edit the content!!
How should I update the table view with new content in the text field through back button?
[image]
[image]

```
let sectionTitles = ["ongoing","Done"]
var list = [String]()

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var objects = sectionTitles.map({_ in return [Any]()})

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton

        if let split = splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
    }

    @objc
    func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) {
        objects[0].insert("Task 1", at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = objects[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! String
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object

                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }
}

class DetailViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescription: UITextField!

    func configureView() {

        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = detailItem {

            if let label = detailDescription {
                label.text = detail.description
                list.append(label.text!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a callback closure which takes a string parameter 2) In `viewDidDisappear`   of the `DetailViewController` call the closure passing the new value. The closure updates the model and reloads the row.

Comment: @vadian what do you mean by callback closure ? do you mean using protocol ?

Comment: No, I mean a callback using a closure which is similar to protocol / delegate but easier to handle and more convenient. It's a very common pattern in Swift.

Comment: @vadian could you give me a example link or description of it

Comment: @arash I wrote an answer. There are only a few (new) lines of code, much less than protocol delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use a callback closure to update the model and reload the row. The callback is called in `viewDidDisappear`. The code in the closure checks if the values are different and updates the model and reloads the row if necessary.

- In DetailViewController create a callback

  ```
  var callback : ((String)->())?
  ```

  - In `viewDidDisappear` call the callback (or maybe already in `viewWillDisappear`)

    ```
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        callback?(detailDescription.text!)
    }
    ```
- In MasterViewController add the closure in `prepare(for`

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
          if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
              let object = objects[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! String
              let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
              controller.detailItem = object
              controller.callback = { newValue in 
                 if object != newValue {
                     self.objects[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = newValue
                     self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                  }
              }
              controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
              controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Value of type 'DetailViewController' has no member 'callback' why am I getting this error?

Comment: Please follow the first step (*In DetailViewController create a callback ...*).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the delegate pattern:

```
protocol DetailViewDelegate: class {
    func detailViewDidUpdate(from: String?, to: String?)
}

class DetailViewController : UIViewController {

    var detailItem: String?

    weak var delegate: DetailViewDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textField.text = detailItem
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.delegate?.detailViewDidUpdate(from: detailItem, to: textField.text)
    }
}
```

Then in your **MasterViewController**:

```
extension MasterViewController: DetailViewDelegate {
    func detailViewDidUpdate(from: String?, to: String?) {
        guard let originalValue = from, let newValue = to else {
            return
        }

        if let indexPath = self.objects.index(of: originalValue) {
            self.objects[indexPath] = newValue
            // We assume here that there is only one section
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath, section: 0)
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to assign the DetailViewController's delegate variable in your MasterController *prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)* method

Comment: And how do you pass the new value back to `MasterViewController`? All collection objects are value type.

Answer (score 0):

When you tapped back button, **viewWillAppear** will be called, its one [View Controller Lifecycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html)

for example

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: And how do you pass the new value back to `MasterViewController`? All collection objects are value type.

Comment: @vadian when using func insertNewObject(_ sender: Any) to add new value, when you insert new value to the array that you use as data source and you reload the table view, new data will appears

Comment: `insertNewObject` is located in `MasterViewController`. The OP wants to edit the value in `DetailViewController` and update the table in `MasterViewController`

Comment: You can pass the new objects throw segue